# How to test a Salesforce install handler?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce

On our managed package, we have a PostInstallClass that implements the [InstallHandler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm) interface. We use it to populate new fields when they are added in later versions, or fix data when the model changes.

However, we have trouble finding a way to test this migrations. For instance: we added a new field that is used in a trigger. We want to insert some records with that field emtpy (as it will be when creating the field), but **without** firing the trigger, which would fail.

Is there any way that we can do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest implementing a protected custom setting object (Protected, because your don't want your subscribers to be able to modify it). This was you can *disable* your trigger e.g

```
trigger <name> on Account (<events>) {
    Configuration_Options__c options = Configuration_Options__c.getOrgDefaults();
    if(options.Trigger_Enabled__c) {
        //perform all the actions in the trigger
    }
}
```

Then in the unit test you can control whether the trigger performs it's actions

```
private static testMethod void testPostInstallClass() {
    PostInstallClass postinstall = new PostInstallClass();
    Configuration_Options__c options = Configuration_Options__c.getOrgDefaults();

    //disable the trigger
    options.Trigger_Enabled__c = false;
    update options;

    //insert your legacy records here

    //re-enable the trigger
    options.Trigger_Enabled__c = true;
    update options;

    //run the install script
    Test.testInstall(postinstall, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is what we ended up doing.